# Angular material : do NOT change color when disabled (add opacity only)

Tags: angular, angular-material, scss-mixins

I'm currently trying to redefine the style of my angular material buttons.

No problem to add new css attributes or change existing ones, but when I'm trying to avoid `color` & `background` changes when the button is `disabled` and add a simple `opacity: 0.5;`, I don't know where to start...

Saw lots of articles about color theming, but none about getting rid of some attributes.

Thanks !

Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
By redefining the mixin `mat-button-theme-property`, I was able to set the opacity and remove undesired CSS attributes.

```
@mixin _mat-button-theme-property($theme, $property, $hue) {
      $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
      $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
      $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
      $background: map-get($theme, background);
      $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);
    
      &.mat-primary {
        #{$property}: mat-color($primary, $hue);
      }
      &.mat-accent {
        #{$property}: mat-color($accent, $hue);
      }
      &.mat-warn {
        #{$property}: mat-color($warn, $hue);
      }
    
      &.mat-primary, &.mat-accent, &.mat-warn, &.mat-button-disabled {
        &.mat-button-disabled {
          // Those lines change the color & background color of the button when disabled
          // $palette: if($property == 'color', $foreground, $background);
          // #{$property}: mat-color($palette, disabled-button);
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }
    }
```

`

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to your `styles.scss` file:

```
.mat-flat-button.mat-primary.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-flat-button.mat-accent.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-flat-button.mat-warn.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-flat-button.mat-button-disabled.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-raised-button.mat-primary.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-raised-button.mat-accent.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-raised-button.mat-warn.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-raised-button.mat-button-disabled.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-fab.mat-primary.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-fab.mat-accent.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-fab.mat-warn.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-fab.mat-button-disabled.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-mini-fab.mat-primary.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-mini-fab.mat-accent.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-mini-fab.mat-warn.mat-button-disabled,
.mat-mini-fab.mat-button-disabled.mat-button-disabled {
    background-color: your-background-color !important;
    color: your-font-color !important;
    opacity: your-desired-opacity !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but using this method I will override the color of the theme.

Comment: You must have to override. Either with color of theme or with your own color choice.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. Because of the primary, accent and warn color, with light and dark theme...

I just found a solution. Posting it as an answer of my post.